# PHP included variable scope

Tags: php, oop, include, scope

So I've got 3 Files

file1.php

```
$var = "string";
```

file2.php

```
include(file1.php); 
include(file3.php); 
echo $var; 
$test = new test();
```

file3.php

```
 class test
 {
   public function __construct()
   {
    if($var = "string") 
    { 
        // do things
    } 
   }
  }
```

Now, the echo in file 2 works fine 
However, in the Test Class, the variable returns a Notice: Undefined variable:
I've tried changing $var to a global, but that didn't seem to help. I imagine I am not understanding scope in PHP correctly with included files. Could anyone help me so I can use $var in the class?

Thanks

Comment: Making it `global` in the constructor would help, but it would be _better_ to pass `$var` into the `__construct()` as in `public function __construct($var){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways this can be done

The wrong way

```
class test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        global $var;
        if($var == "string") 
        { 
            // do things
        } 
    }
}
```

This will import var into the constuctors scope but violates the biggest benefit of object oriented programming which is to encapsulate functionality.

This is the right way

```
class test
{
    public function __construct($var)
    {
        if($var == "string") 
        { 
            // do things
        } 
    }
}

$test = new test($var);
```